# Discover devices (esp8266/arduino) on same LAN subnet

Tags: ionic-framework, udp, lan, arduino-esp8266, service-discovery

I am developing a product which uses ESP8266 (arduino firmware). I am developing an Ionic app as the main controller. The product is working perfectly fine through the server. But a major feature needed is to communicate with the devices through LAN. The devices host a server so I can communicate with them using GET requests through my app using their local IP.

But the problem is discovering these devices. Currently my approach is to send a get request on all IPs on my subnet and parse the response, if any, and store the active IPs in app; then use those stored IPs to communicate for subsequent requests.

The problem is the sending request to all IPs part. It is a slow process and slower with low end phones.

What I want is a way to receive communication from the devices initiated by them, maybe. Something like signalling all IPs (just my devices) at once to send their IPs to my phone.

Can this be done easily? And quickly? And accurately?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set up the ESP8266 to publish an mDNS service (also known as zeroconf, bonjour, etc..).  Luckily, mDNS is built into the ESP8266 Arduino core.  There is some basic setup info here:  https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap08%20-%20mDNS.html, as well as elsewhere on the web.

Then on the ionic side, you can then use a zeroconf/mDNS plugin to automatically discover the ESP8266.  I've used this one in the past, with good results: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/zeroconf/

Comment: I will try this soon and get back to you. Thank you :D