# How to get the IP of hostname in a local Wi-Fi network? Android studio (JAVA)

Tags: android, android-studio, iot, esp8266, nodemcu

What I am trying to do is make an Android App for my NodeMCU so that I can send data via Websockets and not use the browser. I don't want the end user to be inputting any IP addresses to look for the NodeMCU in the network. I understand that you can set a hostname for NodeMCU.

Is there any way I can get the IP of the NodeMCU in the network using its hostname and then further communicate over it?

Comment: What kind of server is running on the NodeMCU? With a fixed port?

Comment: The port will be fixed....so far ive been using port 81 for the websocket and port 80 for viewing the webserver. Yes the ESP will be running as a webserver

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discover devices (esp8266/arduino) on same LAN subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016419/discover-devices-esp8266-arduino-on-same-lan-subnet)

Comment: this is not a question.

Answer (score -1):

You can find ip of server without using its hostname.

Both devices run in the same -wifi- network.

The Android client knows its ip. Say 192.168.2.12.

Now it knows that the ip of the server will be like 192.168.2.##.

Just make a loop where you use a Socket that tries to connect using ip's around the one of the client.

Set a socket time out of two seconds or less.

Comment: That's a bad solution. The network could also be 192.168.##.##. And even just checking 256 IPs with 2 sec timeout, would be 8.5 min.

Comment: Maybe. But here we need only few seconds as the network is a i described and ip addresses are next to each other. @gre_gor. I use it too while travelleng and devices come in guest networks. Always worked.

Comment: @gre_gor: you can open multiple connections to scan, at least 4, maybe 8, so it need not take as long as doing it one at a time.